# LOB in OCI - need explanation/tutorial

Tags: oracle, blob, clob, oracle-call-interface

As someone new to OCI, I find it hard understanding how LOBs work. Can someone please explain?
While I have read the manual and looked at the demos, I am still finding it very hard. 
Are there simple sample codes that just read to and write from multiple LOBs in the same code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- There are various open-source OCI wrapper libs. You can check their source code.
- Also Oracle provides various example sources in db server installation
- You can also find more advanced examples on Metalink

Oracle does distinguish a LOB (data lying in some data segment) and LOB handler (something file file handle in Unix). A lob handle can created only inside the database. For example this statement:

```
insert into t(id, lob_col) values(1, emtpty_blob()) returning lob_col into :bval;
```

This will insert a row into the database, will create an empty BLOB and will return the lob handler to the application. The bind variable "bval" must be registered (bound) as OUT parameter. Here many devs do not understand "why LOB is an out parameter" when they want to "insert" some data. The key point is that lob handle can be created only on the database side. And when you have it you can use it as it was a file handle.

You just have to use OCIRead2/OCIWrire2/OCIOpen/OCIClose functions.

When you want to update a LOB, it's underlying row must be locked:

```
select id, lob_col from t where id = 1 for update;
```

This will return a LOB handle which can be opened for writing. You can write to a LOB handle as long as the transaction is open. When you commit the transaction any further writes to a lob handle will fail.

You can allocate as many lob handles as you want and you can use in any order. Just keep in mind that every lob handle is associated with one DB connection and is valid as long as this connection is alive.

Edited:
One more comment: Do not use OCILobRead but use OCILobRead2. When OCILobRead
Accepts an offset to be read in bytes, but returns a amount of characters read.
When you read UTF8 encoded CLOBS you get a mess when you assume the #bytes=#chars. OCILobRead2 returns both #chars read and also #bytes read.

PS: Warning. A LOB starts with the **1st** byte/char. You can not seek to 0th position.

Comment: I understand how LOBs function, thanks!
What is Metalink though ?

Comment: "Just keep in mind that every lob handle is associated with one DB connection and is valid as long as this connection is alive."
Are you talking about the connection in which I have opened the LOB handles or are you saying that each handle has a separate DB connection ?

Comment: Metalink is Oracle's support portal - you need support contract id to access it. The DB connection is the same, you can not transfer a lob handle from one db connection onto another one.

Comment: For any table tab1(a CLOB), do i need multiple handles for multiple rows ?

Comment: no - you dont. when you fetch a statement and lob locator is defined it will point onto different lob after the fetch. but you can also "clone" lob locator by using OCILobAssign

Comment: you might have problems when you want to communicate with the database in a smart way. When you want to fetch multiple rows at once, you must allocate a set of lob locators. And this is a grey area of Oracle documentation. Theoretically you should call something like OciDefineArrayOfStructures, but it works even without it. For this case you really should check source of some open-source OCI wrapper to check how it work. Finding official example of OCI lib usage is very hard.

Comment: Using the same lob handles seems to work. The usual looping of StmtFetch worked as well!
Thank you so much for your answers !